Problem when testing webframe created using flask
I am trying to test out how openai api works by creating to-do list maker. After writing the code and sending some test using curl. When I tested on terminal it return 200.
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/chatbot -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"message": "Buy groceries, clean the house, sleep for 8 hours"}'

Assuming I would have the result on 127.0.0.1.5000/chatbot I typed localhost:5000/chatbot on chrome then it returns 415 error. Never used flask before so not sure if I am testing it right.
import openai
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)
openai.api_key = 'api_code'

def generate_response(prompt):
    response = openai.completions.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct",
        prompt=prompt,
        max_tokens=150
    )
    return response.choices[0].text.strip()

@app.route('/chatbot', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def chatbot():
    try:
        user_input = request.json['message']
        print(f"Received message: {user_input}")
        prompt = f"Create a to-do list based on the following tasks: {user_input}"
        response_text = generate_response(prompt)
        return jsonify({'response': response_text})
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        return jsonify({'error': 'Internal Server Error'}), 500

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)

I upgraded openai package but it still caused same issue.

Hi, you correctly tested code using curl for POST request. However could you pls also test it for the GET?

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

This snippet will fix the issue. The issue is in "request.json" which only available in body of a POST request. For GET requests you need to pass params in the URL.
For example this are all valid GET requests: 
http://127.0.0.1:5000/chatbot 
http://127.0.0.1:5000/chatbot?message=123 
http://127.0.0.1:5000/chatbot?message=hello 
http://127.0.0.1:5000/chatbot?message=Hello%20World 
import openai
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)
openai.api_key = 'api_code'

def generate_response(prompt):
    # response = openai.completions.create(
    #     model="gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct",
    #     prompt=prompt,
    #     max_tokens=150
    # )
    return "hello"

def chatbot(user_input: str):
    try:
        print(f"Received message: {user_input}")
        prompt = f"Create a to-do list based on the following tasks: {user_input}"
        response_text = generate_response(prompt)
        return jsonify({'response': response_text})
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        return jsonify({'error': 'Internal Server Error'}), 500    


@app.route('/chatbot', methods=['POST'])
def post_chatbot():
    # JSON body only exist in POST requests
    user_input = request.json['message']
    return chatbot(user_input)    


@app.route('/chatbot', methods=['GET'])
def get_chatbot():
    # GET requests use URL params
    # url: http://127.0.0.1:5000/chatbot?message=123
    # url: http://127.0.0.1:5000/chatbot?message=hello
    # url: http://127.0.0.1:5000/chatbot?message=Hello%20World
    user_input = request.args.get('message')
    return chatbot(user_input)    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)

